# Backbone.sync per model

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way to have a different Backbone.sync method invoked for a subset of models in an application?

I have been experimenting with binding models to socket.io, but I don't want all of them to work that way. I would like some of them to stick with REST.

Am I asking the wrong question and overriding sync is the wrong approach?

Comment: If you are reading this for the socket.io part. Backbone.iosync works great. If you are reading for the question of overriding the model the selected answer works great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  sync: function (method, model, options) {}
})
```

Comment: spot on. I should have noticed the (this.sync || Backbone.sync) in the source.

Comment: No problem. Also, I was doing something similar to you recently, and although I am not sure of your exact case, I found that it is much simpler to do everything with socket.io unless there is only one specific thing like chat that uses it. Just my 2 cents.