# Prepend absolute URL path in Backbone.sync for an API on another server

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

My Backbone app communicates with an API that exists on another server. `Backbone.sync` will generate relative URLs by default. The simplest way to prepend the absolute server path would be something like the following:

```coffeescript
MyApp.BASE_URL = "https://api.someOtherSite.com"


class MyApp.Model extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: "#{MyApp.BASE_URL}/my_app_url"
```

However, I'd rather not do this as it isn't DRY. I thought I could try something like the following by overriding `Backbone.sync`:

```coffeescript
do (Backbone) ->
  BASE_URL = 'https://api.someOtherSite.com'
  baseSync = Backbone.sync

  Backbone.sync = (method, model, options) ->
    url = _.result(model, 'url')
    options.url = "#{BASE_URL}/#{url}" if url && !options.url

    baseSync method, model, options
```

However, this is problematic for other parts of the code as the `options` object gets passed around all over the place. *(explanation for the interested at the bottom)

Is there a recommended clean and DRY way to prepend a server path to the front of all URLs generated by `Backbone.sync`?

---

*If the `model` being synced is an instance of `Backbone.Collection` this `options` object will get passed to the collection's model constructor. URL is one of the few properties that will get directly attached to a model if it is passed in as a part of the `options` object. This breaks `sync` for any models that are created in a collection as they now have a set URL attached to them instead of a `url` method that generates an appropriate url by using `urlRoot` or the collection's `url`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.sync per model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772564/backbone-sync-per-model)

Comment: I don't believe this question is asking the same thing. The question you linked to is asking how to have certain models call one `sync` and have others call another. That could be done by simply overriding the model's `sync` method so it does not proxy to `Backbone.sync`.

This question is asking how can I globally modify the URL `sync` calls go to so that they are absolute paths to another server instead of relative ones to the originating server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best option is to create a base model that your other models will extend from:

```
MyApp.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: function(){
             return 'https://api.someOtherSite.com/' + this.get('urlFragment')
  }
});
```

And then have your models be defined like so

```
MyApp.MyModel = MyApp.Model.extend({
  urlFragment: "my_model_url"
})
```

So, in CoffeeScript:

```
class MyApp.Model extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: ->
           'https://api.someOtherSite.com/' + @get('urlFragment')
```

And

```
class MyApp.MyModel extends MyApp.Model
  urlFragment: "my_model_url"
```

Now you've got your urls specified in a DRY fashion!

Comment: I agree that this would be the best solution for the situation. Unfortunately there is no simple way to just specify this option in Backbone.

Another solution would be to override Backbone.Model#url. While monkey patching is normally avoided, this is in the same vein as overriding `Backbone.sync` which the docs suggest you do for non REST storage solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use prototypes to have a universal property across all collections or models etc.

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.absURL  = 'http://example.com';

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model : myModel, 
url: function() {
    return this.absURL + '/api/stuff';
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Know this is old, but I ran into the issue while putting together a client for an api I'm developing. My solution, while dry and very simple, happens in jQuery not Backbone. That said jQuery is a dep of Backbone so I think its a reasonable approach for the typical case.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function prependUrlPrefilter(opts) {
  opts.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' + opts.url;
});
```

One gotcha with this approach is that it globally mutates the url of any xhr calls running through jQuery. If you're calling web services on multiple domains or you have plugins that do and share your same jQuery you'll need to add a condition here.

Also you'll want to abstract the host portion of the domain to a config.

More can be found on ajaxPrefilters [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/).