# Apache Cordova RESTful - Base URL Configuration

Tags: rest, cordova

we are developing an app using Apache Cordova, AngularJS, JavaScript, HTML and CSS. This app will get all of its data from server using jersey RESTful API's. We will use AJAX to interact with server. My question is how can I specify and configure 'base urls' of server in my client app? For example, https://www.mycompany.com. We are having different environments like DEV, QA, PRODUCTION for server side code and thus different urls for each. As Apache Cordova is used for mobile app development, so we are looking for something in Apache Cordova configurations itself, if there exists any?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using BackboneJS. Basically you can create a Backbone model that has the basePath and then having all your model objects extend from that model so they all have the basePath you want. Check the voted answer here: [Prepend absolute URL path in Backbone.sync for an API on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553026/prepend-absolute-url-path-in-backbone-sync-for-an-api-on-another-server).

You may be able to do a similar thing with AngularJS. Check this other post: [Using a Relative Path for a Service Call in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011616/using-a-relative-path-for-a-service-call-in-angularjs)

Hope it helps.